# Hangman project won't correctly identify a win. Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

Currently, I am working on a hangman program in python. I have the basics down, like displaying the blanks and detecting a correct letter, but I cannot figure out to detect when the word or sentence has been correctly identified.

***EDIT***

After reading the comments, I have updated my code, naming my variables using snake_case instead of camelCase and added an output to my show_word function.

```
def show_word(word, known_letters):
    word = word.lower()
    characters = ""

    for i in word:
        if i in known_letters:
            characters = characters + i + " "
        elif i == " ":
            characters = characters + "/ "
        else:
            characters = characters + "_ "

    print characters
    return characters.replace(" ", "").replace("/", " ")

def guess_word(word, known_letters):
    all_letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    word = word.lower()
    guesses = 0

    while show_word(word, known_letters) != word:
        print("Guess a letter")
        guess = raw_input()

        if guess in known_letters:
            print("You have already guessed %s" % (guess))
        elif len(guess) != 1:
            print("Only type one letter")
        else:
            known_letters += guess

        guesses += 1

    print("Well done you have guessed the word(s) (%s) in %s guesses" % (word, guesses))

guess_word("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "")
```

The program now correctly identifies when I have guessed all the correct letters.

Thanks to everyone that helped.

My original code is below if anyone else needs help on this issue.

```
def showWord(word, knownLetters):
    word = word.lower()
    characters = ""

    for i in word:
        if i in knownLetters:
            characters = characters + i + " "
        elif i == " ":
            characters = characters + "/ "
        else:
            characters = characters + "_ "

    print characters

def guessWord(word, knownLetters):
    word = word.lower()
    guesses = 0

    while showWord(word, knownLetters) != word:
        print("Guess a letter")
        guess = raw_input()

        if guess in knownLetters:
            print("You have already guessed %s" % (guess))
        elif len(guess) != 1:
            print("Only guess one letter")
        else:
            knownLetters += guess

        guesses += 1

    print("Well done, you guessed the word (%s) in %s guesses" % (word, guesses))

    showWord(word, knownLetters)

guessWord("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "")
```

Comment: Please never paste an image of code. It discourages anyone from trying to recreate your issue since we can't copy/paste it.

Comment: Your side note should be a separate question when you are ready to ask it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `showWord()` function returns `None` by default since it doesn't explicity return anything.

You should probably add `return characters.replace(' ', '').replace('/', ' ')` after `print characters`, and your end condition should be fulfilled.

You will need to adjust the output of `showWord()` since the letters won't exactly line up with `word`.

When `showWord()` actually returns your string of words, the following statment would equate properly:

```
while showWord(word, knownLetters) != word:
```

will then work as `characters` can be compared against `word`.

Also, it's Python convention to name your variables in snake_case rather than camelCase.

Finally, to redirect you for your bonus question, there are lots of people that have made ASCII Hangman in Python, perhaps you can reference, learn, and adopt those methods. If you have any issues with that, you can ask another question here on Stack Overflow, explicitly showing what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a template of some working code that you can hopefully use to figure out ways to modify your code.

```
def guessWord(word, knownLetters):
    word = word.lower()
    cur_word = ['_'] * len(word)
    result_to_compare = ""

    num_guesses = 0

    while result_to_compare != word:
        print("Guess a letter!")
        guess = raw_input()

        if guess in knownLetters:
            print("You have already guessed this letter!")
        else:
            knownLetters += guess
            for i in range(len(word)):
                if guess is word[i]:
                    cur_word[i] = guess

            print(cur_word)
            result_to_compare = ''.join(cur_word)            

    print("Congrats! You guessed it!")          

guessWord("severe", "")
```

I use cur_word as a temporary variable to show the progress the user is making. After a valid guess I create the string result_to_compare from the values in cur_word and compare it with the actual solution. Hope this helps. This will work with spaces between words as long as the user enters a space as the raw_input. You should be able to figure out how to modify it from here to work as your liking.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version, I made the code as verbose as possible so it should be self explanatory.

```
def showWord(word,knownLetters):
    word=word.lower()
    characters=""
    wordsofar=""
    for char in word:
        if char in knownLetters:
            characters = characters + char + " "
            wordsofar += char
        elif char == " ":
            characters = characters + "/ "
            wordsofar += " "
        else:
            characters += "_ "

    print characters

    return validate(word, wordsofar)

def validate(word, knownLetters):
    word_dict = {}

    for c in word:
        if c not in word_dict:
            word_dict[c] = 1
        else:
            word_dict[c] += 1

    for c in knownLetters:
        if c not in word_dict:
            return False
        else:
            word_dict[c] -=1

    for k,v in word_dict.iteritems():
        if v != 0:
            return False
    return True
```

and then for the while loop, you'll be checking if showWord(word, knownLetters) returns false.